# Oribital comparison

Tags: orbitals

When comparing the orbitals 2s and 2p only in the z axis, do they have the same energy levels and size? I am not so sure just because I know they both have a quantum number of 2. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

(Take any axis , the result would be same)

**Comparision of Energies :**

2p  electrons are higher in energy than 2s ones due to screening effects that result from electron-electron interactions. On average, the 2s electrons will be at a slightly greater distance from the nucleus than the 2p electrons.  However, the 2s electrons have a higher probability of being closer to the nucleus due to the inner peak.  As a result, the 2s orbital will lie lower in energy than the 2p orbital in multi-electron atoms.

The letter of the orbital (s, p, d, etc.) is a nameplace for the azimuthal quantum number (orbital angular momentum, ℓ). The s orbital has ℓ=0, p has ℓ=1. The angular momentum being higher, the energy also is.

**Comparision of Size :**

A p orbital is rather like 2 identical balloons tied together at the nucleus.

The shapes of 2s and 2p can't be compared as they are unique. You can compare all the s orbitals - as these all have the same shape (spherical), equally all the p orbitals (dumb-bell) etc. The only difference there is size - so 1s is a small sphere, 2s is a bigger sphere, 3s even bigger sphere etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is significant difference between s orbitals. ns orbital has n -1 radial nodes.Similarly for p orbitals.